# NullReferenceException occurs when adding effects in the subcontrol

Tags: c#, android, maui

#### `Effects.Add(Effect);` Exception : NullReferenceException

- There is no problem with `Add-Effect` in the `single view`, but `Add-Effect` in the subview of the `nested control` causes an `exception`.

```xml
<!--controls are nested -->
<ContentPage.Content>
    <local:SampleView>
        <local:SampleView.Content>
            <local:SampleView2>
                <local:ContextNullException />
            </local:SampleView2>
        </local:SampleView.Content>
    </local:SampleView>
</ContentPage.Content>
```

#### Stack trace

```
[mono-rt] [ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.get_EffectsFactory() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 14
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.Microsoft.Maui.Controls.IEffectControlProvider.RegisterEffect(Effect effect) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 88
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.AttachEffect(Effect effect) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element.cs:line 547
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_EffectControlProvider(IEffectControlProvider value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\Element.cs:line 250
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.OnHandlerChangedCore() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 35
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.OnHandlerChangedCore() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\VisualElement\VisualElement.Impl.cs:line 40
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.View.OnHandlerChangedCore() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\View\View.Impl.cs:line 16
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.SetHandler(IElementHandler newHandler) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 71
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Element.set_Handler(IElementHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\Element\Element.Impl.cs:line 19
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.VisualElement.set_Handler(IViewHandler value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\HandlerImpl\VisualElement\VisualElement.Impl.cs:line 35
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.RendererToHandlerShim.SetupRenderer(IVisualElementRenderer visualElementRenderer) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Compatibility\Core\src\RendererToHandlerShim.cs:line 100
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.RendererToHandlerShim..ctor(IVisualElementRenderer visualElementRenderer) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Compatibility\Core\src\RendererToHandlerShim.cs:line 91
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android.Platform.<>c.<.cctor>b__66_0(BindableObject bindable, Object oldvalue, Object newvalue) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Compatibility\Core\src\Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:line 44
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueActual(BindableProperty property, BindablePropertyContext context, Object value, Boolean currentlyApplying, SetValueFlags attributes, Boolean silent) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindableObject.cs:line 535
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValueCore(BindableProperty property, Object value, SetValueFlags attributes, SetValuePrivateFlags privateAttributes) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindableObject.cs:line 469
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValue(BindableProperty property, Object value, Boolean fromStyle, Boolean checkAccess) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindableObject.cs:line 391
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.BindableObject.SetValue(BindableProperty property, Object value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Controls\src\Core\BindableObject.cs:line 365
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android.Platform.SetRenderer(VisualElement bindable, IVisualElementRenderer value) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Compatibility\Core\src\Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:line 408
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.AddChild(VisualElement view, IVisualElementRenderer oldRenderer, RendererPool pool, Boolean sameChildren) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Compatibility\Core\src\Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:line 153
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.SetElement(VisualElement oldElement, VisualElement newElement) in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Compatibility\Core\src\Android\VisualElementPackager.cs:line 347
[mono-rt]    at Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Platform.Android.VisualElementPackager.Load() in D:\a\_work\1\s\src\Compatibility\Core\src\Android\VisualEleme
```

Sample Link : https://github.com/SSstupid/Question-list/pull/7

---

#### `relevant code`

##### SampleView

```cs
public class SampleView : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Layout<View>
{
    // Events
    // Properties
    private View _content;
    // If don't do `Children.Insert` and `Children.Remove` , there's no problem.
    // if => View Content { get; set;}
    public View Content
    {
        get => _content;
        set
        {
            if (_content != null)
                Children.Remove(_content);

            _content = value;

            if (_content != null)
                Children.Insert(0, _content);
        }
    }

    // Constructors
    public SampleView()
    {
    }

    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
    }
}
```

##### SampleView2

```cs
public class SampleView2 : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Layout<View>
{
    // Constructors
    public SampleView2()
    {
    }

    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
    }
}
```

##### View : `NullReferenceException`

```cs
public class NullReferenceException : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Compatibility.Layout<View>
{
    public NullReferenceException()
    {
        // In nested Controls :
        // Adding an effect causes a null refence.
        var tapGestureEffect = new TapGestureEffect();
        Effects.Add(tapGestureEffect);
    }

    protected override void LayoutChildren(double x, double y, double width, double height)
    {
    }
}
```

##### custom RoutingEffect

```cs
public class TapGestureEffect : TouchEffect
{
    private readonly IDictionary<long, string> _touchPoints;

    public TapGestureEffect()
    {
        _touchPoints = new Dictionary<long, string>();
    }

    public override void RaiseTouch(Element element, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
        base.RaiseTouch(element, e);
    }
}
```

##### RoutingEffect Base : TouchEffect

```cs
public class TouchEffect : RoutingEffect
{
    public TouchEffect() : base($"SampleContextCanNotBeNull.{nameof(TouchEffect)}")
    {
    }

    public virtual void RaiseTouch(Element element, TouchEventArgs e)
    {
    }
}
```

##### PlatformEffect

```cs
public class TouchPlatformEffect : Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Platform.PlatformEffect
{
    private readonly Dictionary<int, TouchPlatformEffect> idToEffectDictionary = new Dictionary<int, TouchPlatformEffect>();

    protected override void OnAttached()
    {
    }

    protected override void OnDetached()
    {
    }
}
```

##### Effect Register

```cs
public static MauiApp CreateMauiApp()
{
    var builder = MauiApp.CreateBuilder();
    builder
        .ConfigureEffects(effects =>
        {
            effects.Add<TapGestureEffect, TouchPlatformEffect>();
        });
}
```

#### Environment

`Platform` : *Android*
`SDK` :  7.x

Comment: where is `Effects` defined?  What does the stack trace show?

Comment: I add the `stack trace`, and Effects is in `project`, link : https://github.com/SSstupid/Question-list/pull/7/files#diff-9d353c31c9dac8de1593c1da1947da3c3402c343970895876b8d1f55a7898db8

Comment: please read [ask].  Your question should include the relevant code.  You should not expect people to visit your github repo in order to help you.

Comment: Thank you for feedback, and I add the `relevant code`

Comment: I tested the code you provided, tried many things but failed. If it's Ok, please don't use `compatibility.Layout<View>`. Or you can [report it on GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/issues).

Comment: This is a problem the context is null, it has been fixed by setting the context.